# Assign group ID to rows (tags)

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, power-query

I have an Excel 365 table of log entries. The logs are grouped by a start tag and end tag.

[image]

```
Column C: =IF(   LEFT([@LOGS],6)="<Event","start",   IF(LEFT([@LOGS],7)="</Event","end",   ""))
```

---

Raw data:

```
TAG_START_END   LOGS
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.750" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="0"
                Database: C:\2023 Files\GDBs_4\New Mobile Geodatabase.geodatabase
                      SQL: SELECT main.ACTIVE_TRANSPORTATION.OBJECTID,main.active_transportation_nt_flag_vw.flag FRO
end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.749" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="1"

end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.749" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="2"
                Database: C:\2023 Files\GDBs_4\New Mobile Geodatabase.geodatabase
                      SQL: SELECT main.ACTIVE_TRANSPORTATION.OBJECTID,main.active_transportation_nt_flag_vw.flag FRO
                      Number of features returned: 100
end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.749" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="0"

end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.747" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="0"
                Database: C:\2023 Files\GDBs_4\New Mobile Geodatabase.geodatabase
                      SQL: SELECT main.ACTIVE_TRANSPORTATION.OBJECTID,main.active_transportation_nt_flag_vw.flag FRO
end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.747" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="2"
                Database: C:\2023 Files\GDBs_4\New Mobile Geodatabase.geodatabase
                      SQL: SELECT main.ACTIVE_TRANSPORTATION.OBJECTID,main.active_transportation_nt_flag_vw.flag FRO
                      Number of features returned: 100
end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.746" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="1"

end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.746" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="0"

end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.744" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="0"
                Database: C:\2023 Files\GDBs_4\New Mobile Geodatabase.geodatabase
                      SQL: SELECT main.ACTIVE_TRANSPORTATION.OBJECTID,main.active_transportation_nt_flag_vw.flag FRO
end             </Event>
start           <Event time="Sat Apr 15 1:13:17.743" type="Debug" thread="2fec: Main CIM worker thread" elapsed="1"

end             </Event>
```

For each tag group, I want to populate the GROUP_ID column.

In the screenshot above, I've manually typed in the values in that field. Now, I want to find a way to populate the field using a formula or Power Query.

---

How can I populate the GROUP_ID column?

Reason: I want to eventually find a way to pivot the LOGS info into columns: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfTUV.png. I figure a GROUP_ID column would help with that.

---

Related:

[Copy Diagnostic Monitor logs as Excel table, not as vertical tags](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/copy-diagnostic-monitor-logs-as-excel-table-not-as/idc-p/1279275/highlight/true#M24493)

---

Edit:

This is how it can be done using SQL:

> Oracle SQL - [Assign GROUP_ID to rows based on start/end tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76021834/5576771)
>
> ```
> sum(case when log_tags like '<Event%' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id)
> ```

Can something similar be done in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With PowerQuery, you can define `AddGroup` and `AddSeq` steps which reference themself if the result is well defined. Such recursive definitions need a `@` in the name of each step when referencing them.

```ocaml
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    TypeChanged = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TAG_START_END", type text}, {"LOGS", type text}}),
    IndexAdded = Table.AddIndexColumn(TypeChanged, "Index", 0, 1),
    AddSeq = Table.AddColumn(IndexAdded, "Seq", 
       each if [TAG_START_END]="start" then 1 else @AddSeq[Seq]{[Index]-1} +1),
    AddGroup = Table.AddColumn(AddSeq, "GroupID", 
       each if [TAG_START_END]="start" 
            then (if [Index]=0 then 1 else @AddGroup[GroupID]{[Index]-1}+1) 
            else @AddGroup[GroupID]{[Index]-1})
in
    AddGroup
```

Here IndexAdded inserts an index column needed to reference the table one cell up (`{[Index]-1}`)

Here, I have used the C column (start/end), but `Text.StartsWith` could be used to compute the start condition in PowerQuery.

The script can be enhanced to reorder the columns, or suppress the index column.

---

This query is easy to write (if we know about recursive construction of a table), but not very efficient.

Here is a new, optimised version (3s for 2000 lines). It takes directly a `LOGS` column, verify if it starts with `<Event`, if yes, start a new group sequence.

```ocaml
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table"]}[Content],
    TypeChanged = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"LOGS", type text}}),
    Lines = Table.ToRecords(TypeChanged),
    Result = List.Accumulate(Lines, [table={}, group=0, seq=0],
        (state, current) => if Text.StartsWith(current[LOGS],"<Event")
            then let g = state[group]+1, s = 1 in
                 [ table= state[table] & {[group=g,seq=s] & current},
                   group=g, seq=s] 
            else let g = state[group], s = state[seq]+1 in
                 [ table= state[table] & {[group=g,seq=s] & current},
                   group=g, seq=s] ),
    Table1 = Result[table],
    Table2 = Table.FromRecords(Table1)
in
    Table2
```

Comment: Thanks! Did you find the performance of the query to be extremely slow? It seems to take several minutes to process ~200 rows (need to process ~2500 rows eventually). Roughly 2 seconds per row. Is that due to the recursive nature of the query?

Comment: OK, new version added.

Comment: I guess that each lines of array with the first query recomputes all the previous lines. I havn't expected it to be so unoptimized. The second proposition uses a linear loop (`List.Accumulate`), but it is not as straightforward. I leave the first query here as the `@query[column]{[Index]-1}` may be quite handy with limited cases.

Comment: That new version works well/fast. Thanks. For my notes, I got an error when I used the new version on certain data: `Evaluation resulted in stack overflow and cannot continue.` https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDEG.png. But with other data, it worked fine. I don't know if it's a data issue or a Power Query issue. Power Query seems to get hung up at the `Result` step: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH34v.png.

Comment: I had once the stack overflow in the query editor, but never in the Excel sheet while actualizing the query output.